# Erro number_format

Tags: php

Boa noite pessoal.

Tenho essa função para converter o valor americano para brasileiro

```
function Real($valor){
    $valor_real = number_format($valor,2, ',', '.');
    return $valor_real;
}
```

Ele funciona certinho, mas qdo vai exibir casas com milhar Ex. 1.250,00 ele exibe apenas 1,00

Podem me ajudar?

Chamo a função dessa maneira

```
R$ <?=Real($lnP['produto_atributo_preco']); ?>
```

No mysql o campo está como DECIMAL(10,2) estava como VARCHAR e mesmo assim esta com esse erro

Obrigado

Comment: No banco esse valor fica armazenado como "1250.00"? Pode confirmar isso?

Comment: no banco grava assim @AndersonCarlosWoss 1,250.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vírgulas como separador de milhar (formato americano) confundem o `number_format`. Remova e deixe só o ponto como separador decimal:

```
$valor = '1,250.00';
$valor_real = number_format($valor,2, ',', '.');

echo $valor_real; // 1,00

$valor = str_replace(',', '', $valor); // 1250.00
$valor_real = number_format($valor,2, ',', '.');

echo $valor_real; // 1.250,00
```

**[Exemplo](https://eval.in/826026)**

Comment: Deu certinho manow... mudei na tabela de decimal para varchar e funfou...

Comment: Varchar é gambiarra, não solução. Formate corretamente o valor antes de inserir no banco com a coluna tipo decimal e não terá problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Não pode mandar gravar no banco assim 1,250.00 com DECIMAL(10,2) não, se vc tentar inserir esse valor ele vai gravar no banco 1.00 e quando vc aplicar sua função nele vira 1,00 Nesse caso faça teste  [**aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/_real.php)

Para campos DECIMAL(10,2), na hora do insert tem que ser nesses formatos 1250.00 ou 123456.00 ou 1234567.89 etc, ou seja, separador ponto (.) somente na casa dos decimais.

Outra solução ( a la gambiarra ) é usar Varchar para o campo.